# Packet logging on windows

Tags: c++, windows, packet-capture

Are there any methods to log incoming packets other than wincap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Netmon](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en) is a free download.

> Network Monitor 3.4 is a protocol
>   analyzer. It allows you to capture
>   network traffic, view and analyze it.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for the implementation of code using packet capturing methods.

Comment: Try Windows Filtering Platform http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366510(v=vs.85).aspx.  If you want already-written code, I don't know.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still on XP, WFP seems to support Vista & above. if nothing else then wcap would do.

Comment: There is a more basic packet filtering API (with limited logging built in) on Windows XP - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376646.aspx